# How to prevent Redux from transforming immutable data (when using transit.fromJSON)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm relatively new to Redux, yet from my observations, all data in the redux store is immutable and once it gets mapped to props, it's converted to normal JS objects.

I have a case where my 'payload' is an immutable object (immutable nested Map). This object is being stored to a database using the 'transit.toJSON' function. Using another action/reducer, this object can be retrieved, using the 'transit.fromJSON' function.

Prior to reduxifying the app, using this transit function worked fine (transit.fromJSON was converting the data into the proper immutable form). Yet now with redux, the object is being returned as a normal JS object.

The only difference is the transit.fromJSON/transit.toJSON are now being implemented in a reducer (versus in react component functions).

In the component (submitting object to db):

```
onSubmit() {
    var data = {'data_item': transit.toJSON(item)}
    this.props.saveItem(data)
}
```

In the action (for saving the object to database):

```
 const saveItem = (data) => async(dispatch) => {
      const response = await REST.post('/save_item', data)
      dispatch({
        'type': ITEM_SAVED,
        'payload': response.data,
        });
      }
     catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
```

In the action to retrieve object from database:

```
 try{
    const response = await REST.get('/get_data_item?id='+item_id)
    dispatch({
        'type': FETCH_ITEM,
        'payload': response.data,
    })
 }
catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

In the reducer (after retrieving object form database):

```
case action.FETCH_ITEM:
    return state.set('dataItem', transit.fromJSON(payload.data_item)
```

mapStateToProps:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const store = state.reportbuilder.toJS();
    return {'dataItem': store.dataItem}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux itself doesn't do any transformation.  Redux doesn't even know what your actual data is.  *You* are responsible for all of that, by writing reducers that work with certain data types, and extracting that data in your `mapStateToProps` functions.

If you can give some specific examples of what data you're working with and where it's being "transformed" in unexpected ways, that might help.  But, in general, *you* are responsible for writing all the code that manipulates that data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I updated my question, hope it helps.

Comment: Can you show some actual code, and point to where the data is showing up in an unexpected format?

Comment: And can you show the `mapStateToProps` function and the render method?

Comment: I think you just nailed it.  As you can see in the code i just added (mapStateToProps). I was converting the entire store to normal JS using the toJS function! Cant believe i didn't catch that before. Thank you!

Comment: Yep.  Like I said - it's _your_ reducer code that determines what goes into the store, and _your_ `mapState` function that determines what goes from the store to the components.  Note that in general, [calling `toJS()` in a `mapState` function is a bad idea!](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#immutablejs-performance-concerns).  If you _must_ do that, use [a memoized selector function](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/) so it only converts when the Immutable object is changed.